# React Native FlatList item with different positions (Type Vertical Scroll Game Map)

Tags: listview, react-native, render, expo, imagebackground

**HI GUYS...**

**CONTEXT** I am working with a react-native app (SDK-30) using Expo (30.0.1) where i need build a item list with vertical orientation. I using a FlatList that is responsible to draw the items in the screen, but under FlastList i have a  that render a image type Map Game Vertical.

**NEED** I need position each item by orden above the road image.

[image]

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS**

-Position absolute to each item and put  negative value and positive value consecutively, So the first item will be in the left and the next in the right.

-Put directly each item in a specify position and don't use the FlatList.

**PROBLEMS**

The problem with the previous solutions is that each postition change depending of device sizes.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

-In using a .jpg with specific sizes

-I need put approximately 200 items for that reason i'm using a FlatList that render segments of 20 items and each segment have a image.

**Have you any idea to solve it?**

Answer (score 1):

I made one attempt at: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/correct-positioning

The resolution changes might need some extra fine tuning, especially if the ratio is different (when the image will transform). You need to draw several backgrounds and apply them based on the current screen ratio.

I won't paste the actual code here, but feel free to check the Snack and then make evaluations whether it's more usable than your current implementation.